# Amount (percentage of sodium in meat being cooked) of sodium left in water (broth) after cooking meat

Tags: sodium

On a low sodium diet (AFib and Congestive Heart Failure)- cooking stew- want to use the stock as a broth substitute- how do I figure the amount of sodium from the meat left in the broth?

Comment: Are you adding salt in the stew?   Not getting stock from a stew.

Comment: I think the question is on how much sodium gets extracted from the meat and other ingredients.

Comment: Thanks- I KNEW there had to be something out there!!!! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options to measure the amount of salt in the soup. Measure the salt content directly by weight, or measure the electrical conductivity of the broth.

For either solution you need to filter the soup as much as possible preferable until it is almost clear.

Solution 1: Cook the filtered soup until it is dry and stops smoking, weigh the leftover residue that would be mostly salt.

Solution 2: Get a meter that detects the mineral content by testing electrical conductivity. Get something like this http://amzn.to/2u8pdwM and you can calculate the approximate amount of salt from that reading.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to actually measure it - most people here hope that there is a simple formula to predict stuff, but reality is usually too messy for that.